# Can't connect BigQuery to CloudSQL Postgres instance in us-east1

Tags: google-bigquery

I get the following error when I try to create connection between BigQuery and CloudSQL-Postgres instance in us-east1-c;

> Cloud SQL instance must be in the same location as the connection.
>   Cloud SQL instance location: us-east1, connection location: us-east4

Only region available in us-east is `us-east4` as I see in connection options - which is not the location we have our database on.

Is Google planning to support more region options for BigQuery-CloudSQL connection, is there any work-around?